# Get The Most Recent Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join, greatest-n-per-group

In SQL Server, I am using two tables (AOC_MODEL and PACKAGE that I have joined together. I want to get the most recent version from the I_FW Column for every AOC_ID.

```
SELECT
    AOC_MODEL.AOC_ID,
    AOC_MODEL.CONTROLLER, 
    AOC_MODEL.AOC_FORM_FACTOR, 
    PACKAGE.I_FW, 
    PACKAGE.ETRACK_ID, 
    PACKAGE.ECO,
    PACKAGE.ECO_DATE
FROM            
    AOC_MODEL 
    INNER JOIN PACKAGE
        ON AOC_MODEL.AOC_ID = PACKAGE.AOC_ID
WHERE CONTROLLER LIKE 'intel%'
```

I expect to be able to show one record with the highest number from `I_FW` column for any given `AOC_ID`.

Like on the attached picture, I would like to see 2 items only where `AOC_ID` `117` has the highest number of `1.93` comparing to the other `117` items as well as `AOC_ID` `118` with number `1.20`. So in this case, I would like to see ONLY two items instead of 11.

[image: SQL Query]

Comment: Please look into Max() and Min(). In your case something like Max(I_FE) ...

Comment: There are two records with `aoc_id = 117` and `i_fw = 1.93`. In this situation, which one do you want to pick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like this:

```
SELECT AOC_MODEL.AOC_ID
       , AOC_MODEL.CONTROLLER
       , AOC_MODEL.AOC_FORM_FACTOR
       , MAX(PACKAGE.I_FW)
       , MAX(PACKAGE.ETRACK_ID)
       , MAX(PACKAGE.ECO)
       , MAX(PACKAGE.ECO_DATE)
FROM AOC_MODEL INNER JOIN PACKAGE
ON AOC_MODEL.AOC_ID = PACKAGE.AOC_ID
WHERE CONTROLLER LIKE 'intel%'
GROUP BY AOC_MODEL.AOC_ID
         , AOC_MODEL.CONTROLLER
         , AOC_MODEL.AOC_FORM_FACTOR
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0800968b3c92442cefcc3a1a362ff070)

Comment: Awesome... Thank you very much. I was playing with GROUP BY but not at the correct syntax

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to help. Be aware that this will also give you max value from columns: ETRACK_ID, ECO and ECO_DATE

Comment: @jbegic . . . I don't see how this does what you want.  The four columns from `PACKAGE` could all come from different rows, not the row with the maximum `I_FW` value.

Comment: @jbegic , Gordon Linoff is correct. As I have commented when posting the answer : `Be aware that this will also give you max value from columns: ETRACK_ID, ECO and ECO_DATE`.  So, you might not get the values from the row where the max I_FW value comes from. I have added a DEMO with few simple and fake rows of data so you can check the result of this query. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a correlated subquery that recovers the highest `i_wf` for the current `aoc_id` and use it to filter the join on `package`, like so:

```
select
    a.aoc_id,
    a.controller, 
    a.aoc_form_factor, 
    p.i_fw, 
    p.etrack_id, 
    p.eco,
    p.eco_date
from            
    aoc_model a
    inner join package p
        on a.aoc_id = p.aoc_id
        and p.i_wf = (
            select max(p1.i_wf)
            from package p1
            where p1.aoc_id = p.aoc_id
        )
where controller like 'intel%'
```

For performance, consider an index on `package(aoc_id, i_wf)`.

Note: table aliases make the query easier to read and understand; I modified your query accordingly.

Comment: This would return two rows with ID = 117 ? Right? From the example data OP has given ?

Comment: That helped a lot but it was still leaving duplicates on occasion (like I would still have a duplicate on 117 id and some other ID's randomly. The answer below from VBoksic was spot on

Comment: Happy to help... If the answer below helped please do mark it as accepted and up vote would be great also :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this is what you want:

```
SELECT m.AOC_ID, m.CONTROLLER,  m.AOC_FORM_FACTOR, 
       p.I_FW, p.ETRACK_ID, p.ECO, p.ECO_DATE
FROM AOC_MODEL m JOIN
     (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AOC_ID ORDER BY I_FW DESC) as seqnum
      FROM PACKAGE p
     ) p
     ON m.AOC_ID = p.AOC_ID
WHERE aoc.CONTROLLER LIKE 'intel%' AND p.seqnum = 1;
```

All the values from `PACKAGE` in the result set come from the set row.